# using javascript filter() with a flag

Tags: javascript

I want to return `arr2` but want to prompt the user whether there's changes or not by comparing it with arr. with below's approach, I got id of undefined if `arr2` have any missing item.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'something2'
}]

var arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}]

var result = arr.filter(function(obj, i) {
  return obj.id == arr2[i].id;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: I'm not convinced you are going about this the right way.  Are you guaranteed that the IDs will be in the same order?  What if arr2 had the same 2 hashes but in a different order?  Should that be detected as a change? Or if the name changes?

Comment: @karina IDs will be the same. But does the order matter?

Comment: Wait... That is what I'm asking you.  Does order in the array matter?  For instance if the IDs in each array were [1,2] and [2,1] would you consider that a 'change'

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `arr[1]` is undefined and you are trying to get `id` property of undefined. Now what you can do is, get id's in array then get index and check based on that in filter.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'something2'
}]

var arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}];

var arrIds = arr2.map(function(v) {
  return v.id;
});

var result = arr.filter(function(obj) {
  var i = arrIds.indexOf(obj.id);
  return i > -1 &&
    obj.name == arr2[i].name; // check name property here
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: @Rayon :  what to do with array length here

Comment: @Rayon : `arr[i]` will be undefined after reaching max index

Comment: Suppose `array` is of length `3` and `arr2` is of length `5`, `.filter` handler will be invoked for only `3` time...not 5.. Correct me if I am reading things wrong..

Comment: @Rayon : question is little bit unclear to me..... let us wait for his response....

Comment: Test this input: `var arr2 = [{
  id: 9,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}];`

Comment: this is enough, arr2 won't be greater than arr1, as in my case im using this for an ecommerce solution. Check if these item exist or not in db then filter the returned obj with the current item in the cart. But is it possible to do a flag? telling the user some item is not available or the price has changed?

Comment: @JamieJordan : missing one element would change the order in array

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `arr2` in a `callback` of the `.filter` to test each item of `arr2`.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'something2'
}]

var arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'something'
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: 'something'
}];

var isValInArr = function(arr, key, val) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i][key] === val) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

var result = arr.filter(function(obj, i) {
  return isValInArr(arr2, 'id', obj.id);
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: will this check whether the item arrays has the same property or not?

Comment: @JamieJordan, I did not get you :(

Comment: means for the id that has the value of 1, how to check whether its name value has changed, not `something` but something else.